# Pug tag names with at-signs/asperands (@)

Tags: gulp, pug, pugjs

I use pug to write `.json` files (compiled with `gulp`, `gulp-pug` and `gulp-xml2json`).

It works really well normally, but I can't figure out how to get it to handle the asperands (`@`) necessary for [`json-ld` structured data](https://json-ld.org/). I've tried every type of [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#tag-interpolation) I can think of, including the method suggested by the author for a similar problem (see [issue #2783](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2783) on github), but haven't had any luck.

Is there a simple solution I'm overlooking?

**This works**

```
// data.json.xml.pug   

root
  context https://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld
```

compiles to

```
// data.json

{
  "context": "https://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld"
}
```

**This doesn't**

```
// data.json.xml.pug   

root
  @context https://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld
```

> unexpected text "@cont"

**This doesn't either**

```
// data.json.xml.pug   

root
  #{'@context'} https://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld
```

> Error: Error: Unencoded <
>
> ...
>
> Char: @

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Answer](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2783#issuecomment-388799194) from [@ForbesLindsay](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay) on GitHub (thanks!)—

```
#{'@context'}
```

produces

```
<@context></@context>
```

The problem you're having is that `xml2json` doesn't interpret that as valid xml (because it isn't) you will need to find out if there is any valid xml string that produces your desired JSON, then you can figure out how to generate that XML in pug.